# appengine python routing - confirming back in google app engine console

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app with 2 modules (default and module1). The dispatch.yaml looks below . ( The app is a python application deployed on google app engine).

```
application: myapp

dispatch:
   # Default module serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
   - url: "*/favicon.ico"
     module: default

   # Send  all mobile traffic to the mobile frontend.
   - url: "*/mobile/*"
     module: module1
```

This seems to work successfully.

But after a live deployment is complete, where can we go and confirm the same in google engine console ( like cron.yaml lists the jobs ) about the current routing in place. This will be very useful to debug live issues, to understand current routing ( dispatch.yaml ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dispatch rules active, they should be visible in the admin console under the "Main > Dispatch" left navigation link.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot see the routes in place declared the app.yaml file or ones created dynamically, for that matter, in the app engine dashboard. It's a limitation of the system.